# Why isn't my sump pump kicking on?

Tags: plumbing, pump

My sump pump is not kicking on and has water standing.  The water also seems to have oil in it.  Don't know what that is from but I don't want it to flood my basement.  What should I do?

Comment: Does your sump pump have power?

Comment: My pump stands in a certain amount of water all the time. I don't think a little oil sheen is unusual or uncommon in sump water. If you pour a 5 gallon bucket of water into your sump does the pump kick on? I do that a couple of times a year with mine just to check and exercise the pump. If it doesn't, shop-vac the water out and replace it like Tester says.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need a new pump.

Submersible pumps are often filled with a non-conductive [mineral oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil).  If the oil is no longer in the pump, the pump is probably dead.